# Acces router clients over VPN network

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openwrt

I have the following VPN network, and the issue is, how to acces the raspberry pi or any OpenWRT Router VPN CLIENT with 192.168.8.X   IP address.

I can acces the OpenWRT VPN CLIENT with 10.8.0.6 from my laptop, but no response to 192.168.8.1 ping.

Also, i can reach the server IP 192.168.1.1 from my laptop.

```
####################  
# my laptop        #  
# VPN IP 10.8.0.10 #   
####################
        |
        |
        | internet
        |
        |   
#########################
# OpenWRT VPN SERVER    # 
# VPN IP 10.8.0.1       #        
# Router ip 192.168.1.1 #
#########################          
        |
        |
        | internet
        |
        |   
#########################      ####################     
# OpenWRT VPN CLIENT    #-----># Raspberry Pi     #
# VPN IP 10.8.0.6       #      #                  #  
# Router ip 192.168.8.1 #      # IP 192.168.8.123 # 
#########################      ####################
```

And for VPN Server config file i have:

```
config openvpn 'myvpn'
        option enabled '1'
        option verb '3'
        option proto 'udp'

        option dev 'tun'
        option dev 'tun0'
        option topology subnet
        option pull

        option server '10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0'
        option keepalive '10 120'
        option ca '/etc/openvpn/ca.crt'
        option cert '/etc/openvpn/my-server.crt'
        option key '/etc/openvpn/my-server.key'
        option dh '/etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem'
        option port 'XXXX'
        option client_to_client '1'
        option down '/usr/bin/ovpn-down'

        list push 'route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0'
        list push 'route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0'
        list push 'route 192.168.8.0 255.255.255.0'

        list push 'dhcp-option DNS 192.168.10.1'
        list push 'dhcp-option DNS 192.168.8.1'

        list push 'route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255'
        list push 'route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0'

        list push 'redirect-gateway def1'
```

Adding new info:

Server routes:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 pppoe-wan
10.0.0.1        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 pppoe-wan
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
```

Also added a new route on the server:

```
192.168.8.0     10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

Client config file:

```
dev tun
proto udp
route 192.168.8.0/24
log openvpn.log
verb 3
client
remote-cert-tls server
remote dns.server.com XXXX
```

Client route table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
xx.xx.xx.xx     192.168.100.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.8.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
192.168.10.0    10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     10     0        0 eth0
```

Also, I've tried without the `list push 'route 192.168.8.0 255.255.255.0'` option and i still can't get access to network ip 192.168.8.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't want to push 182.168.8.0 for a start, as that range belongs on the LAN. You might want it as a route, as it belongs on the server, but it's probably unnecessary as the redirect-gateaybdhould endure packets are routed. Also, make sure you don't have any iptables NAT rules covering 192.168.0.0/16 which are not bound to the wan if only on the opener router.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.